# How to link a node with a next node in Java

Tags: java

I will begin by creating the head node:

```
Node head = new Node();
```

To link head node to the next node. I will assign to the field of type Node in node object

The zero is to represent the number of the node. This node is number zero.

```
Node node = new Node(0,head);

public class Node {

  private Object data;
  private Node next;

  public Node()
  {
    data = null;
    next = null;
  }

  public Node(Object x)
  {
    data = x;
    next = null;
  }

  public Node(Object x, Node nextNode)
  {
    data = x;
    next = nextNode;
  }
}
```

Is this the proper way to link nodes together?

Comment: Does it work? Does it meet your requirements?

Comment: The issue with this is your forced to make the list from the end to the start (the last item you make is at the beginning).

Comment: I don't understand. How could this be? I thought the nodes being created are from beginning to end because I'm trying to link head to the first node

Comment: @user983246 What is your purpose with the "node"? What are you using it for? What kind of node is it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I normally see is using a LinkedList.

```
public class Node {
    public Object data;
    public Node next = null;

    Node(data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}

class LinkedList{
    public Node head = null;
    public Node end = null;

    void insert(Object data) {
        if(head == null) {
            head = new Node(data);
            end = head;
        } else {
            end.next = new Node(data);
            end = end.next;
        }
    }
}
```

This is used as follows:

```
LinkedList= new LinkedList();
list.insert(2);
list.insert(3);
list.head;
```

Comment: Thanks. This is definitely a nicer way to look at linkedlist.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you refer to all objects via references (i.e., pointers). The only time you deal with actual values is with primitive types.

So doing `next = nextNode` causes `next` to point to the same location that `nextNode` points to.

**TL;DR;** Yes. :)

Comment: I thought assignment work from right to left. But the way you are saying it, assignment works from left to right.