# Max Page Calculation Algorithm

Tags: java

I want to be able to calculate the maxPages needed.

I have two variables to be considered: totalObjects (Objects to be put into the page) sizeOfPage

totalObjects could be anything between 1-100 so this maxPage algorithm should work for all.

maxPage will be at least 1.

`sizeOfPage will be factors of 9, the minimum is 9. 
Ex. sizeOfPage could be set to 9, 18, 27 etc.`

a variable that should be used is perPage, this will include an amount of totalObjects that can fit.
However, this should also consider that there could be a next page slot taken or previous page slot taken.

`If page is = 1 it won't have a previous page slot taken
if page is > 1 < maxPage it will have a previous and next page slot.
if page == maxPage it should not have a next page slot taken.`

I'm unsure how I could go about writing this logic in Java.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What is the exact problem? You state its about calculations, though in the end its about [linking Nodes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15367810/how-to-link-a-node-with-a-next-node-in-java).

Comment: @n247s I'm unsure how to go about implementing this.